# Tomcat9 Log4j2 - Logging is Different Between Two Servers

Tags: java, centos7, log4j2, tomcat9, jelastic

I am running two different Tomcat9 servers (DEV, PROD), each at separate CentOS 7 service providers, and the app logs generated, using the same log4j2.xml, are different. In the DEV version I get a full log of com.example, but in the PROD version I only get org.hibernate logging.

Both servers are configured similarly (shown further down). Both use same log4j2.xml, MyWebApp.war deployed on each Tomcat is identical.

Both Tomcats are standard installs - meaning, I have not added any log4j jars or properties to either one.

I hope someone has some things to consider.

Thanks,

Bob

**DEV Config:**

```
 Provider: VPS
 rpm -q centos-release
    centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64 

 java -cp /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.20/lib/catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
    Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.20
    Server built:   May 3 2019 22:26:00 UTC
    Server number:  9.0.20.0
    OS Name:        Linux
    OS Version:     2.6.32-042stab127.2
    Architecture:   amd64
    JVM Version:    1.8.0_212-b04
    JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

**PROD Config:**

```
 Provider: Jelastic
 rpm -q centos-release
    centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64

 java -cp /opt/tomcat/lib/catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
    Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.19
    Server built:   Apr 12 2019 14:22:48 UTC
    Server number:  9.0.19.0
    OS Name:        Linux
    OS Version:     3.10.0
    Architecture:   amd64
    JVM Version:    1.8.0_202-b08
    JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

**log4j2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logPath">/home/example/logs</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d [%t] %-5p [%C.%M()] %m%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="rollingFile" fileName="${logPath}/MyWebApp.log"
            filePattern="${logPath}/cucumber-log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d [%t] %-5p [%C.%M()] %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                    modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="console" level="warn"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile" level="warn"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="debug" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="console" level="debug"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.example" level="trace" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="console" level="trace"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile" level="trace"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**mywebapp.war:**

[image]

**DEV MyWebApp.log** (end of hibernate AND beginning of mywebapp logging):

```
2019-06-13 05:18:36,998 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService()] No JtaPlatform was specified, checking resolver
2019-06-13 05:18:36,998 [main] TRACE [org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService()] Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatformResolver]
2019-06-13 05:18:37,002 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformResolverInitiator.initiateService()] No JtaPlatformResolver was specified, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver]
2019-06-13 05:18:37,027 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver.resolveJtaPlatform()] Could not resolve JtaPlatform, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2019-06-13 05:18:37,028 [main] INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService()] HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2019-06-13 05:18:37,031 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries()] Checking 0 named HQL queries
2019-06-13 05:18:37,031 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries()] Checking 0 named SQL queries
2019-06-13 05:18:37,032 [main] TRACE [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration.sessionFactoryCreated()] Handling #sessionFactoryCreated from [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@35c7c5e] for TypeConfiguration
2019-06-13 05:18:37,036 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.<init>()] Initializing SessionFactoryRegistry : org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry@2ebf0e46
2019-06-13 05:18:37,037 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.addSessionFactory()] Registering SessionFactory: 7ffcae61-38d8-4cc8-9cc2-4889b35589f0 (<unnamed>)
2019-06-13 05:18:37,038 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.addSessionFactory()] Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
2019-06-13 05:20:23,717 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-1] WARN  [com.example.tanglemydata.controller.AccountController.getAllAdData()] ENTRY
2019-06-13 05:20:23,719 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG [com.example.tanglemydata.service.AccountService.getAllAdData()] ENTRY
2019-06-13 05:20:23,794 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-1] TRACE [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession()] Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=null, owner=null
2019-06-13 05:20:24,088 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-1] TRACE [org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService()] Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.resource.transaction.spi.TransactionCoordinatorBuilder]
2019-06-13 05:20:24,254 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-1] TRACE [org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService()] Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
2019-06-13 05:20:24,295 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG [org.hibernate.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator.initiateServiceInternal()] Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
2019-06-13 05:20:24,303 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-1] TRACE [org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService()] Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.jmx.spi.JmxService]
2019-06-13 05:20:24,319 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-1] TRACE [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>()] Opened Session [3eb81c15-c50c-44a5-9825-5e31d3cb2172] at timestamp: 1560403224040
```

**PROD MyWebApp.log** (last 9 entries):

```
2019-06-13 04:39:40,435 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService()] No JtaPlatform was specified, checking resolver
2019-06-13 04:39:40,437 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformResolverInitiator.initiateService()] No JtaPlatformResolver was specified, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver]
2019-06-13 04:39:40,505 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver.resolveJtaPlatform()] Could not resolve JtaPlatform, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2019-06-13 04:39:40,506 [main] INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService()] HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2019-06-13 04:39:40,509 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries()] Checking 0 named HQL queries
2019-06-13 04:39:40,509 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries()] Checking 0 named SQL queries
2019-06-13 04:39:40,513 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.<init>()] Initializing SessionFactoryRegistry : org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry@34e10162
2019-06-13 04:39:40,514 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.addSessionFactory()] Registering SessionFactory: bba8ac5f-afd5-4b89-ba16-77f5c980fa0e (<unnamed>)
2019-06-13 04:39:40,515 [main] DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.addSessionFactory()] Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
```

**DEV cmdline:**

```
cat /proc/23517/cmdline
/usr/bin/java-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.20/conf/logging.properties-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources-Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027-Dignore.endorsed.dirs=-classpath/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.20/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.20/bin/tomcat-juli.jar-Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.20-Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.20-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.20/temporg.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrapstart
```

**PROD cmdline:**

```
cat /proc/19765/cmdline
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java.orig-javaagent:/java_agent/jelastic-gc-agent.jar=period=300,debug=0-XX:+UseStringDeduplication-XX:+UseG1GC-Xmaxf0.3-Xminf0.1-Xmx614M-Xmn30M-Xms32M-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager-DReceiverIp=-DMagicPort=-XX:+UseCompressedOops-server-Djvm=tomcat-Djava.awt.headless=true-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false-DjvmRid=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources-Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027-Dignore.endorsed.dirs=-classpath/opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar-Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat-Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temporg.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrapstarttomcat
```

Comment: Run ps aux in both servers and find the process id for each one. Then run cat /proc/{proc_id}/cmdLine for both process and find the arguments passed. Search for any logging level argument.

Comment: @Perimosh - I hadn't thought of looking at the cmdline - thanks. I edited the post, and added DEV and PROD cmdlines.  They both include logging.properties, but the files are identical. I'm not seeing anything else in the PROD cmdline that would affect logging - do you?

Comment: Your DEV and PROD seems to be the same, I see some differences though. From a continuos integration and release perspective, if DEV is your last environment before deploying to PROD, then they should look "almost" the same. Anyway, did you check that these:

prod java.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
prod catalina.home=/opt/tomcat

dev catalina.home=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.20
dev  java.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.20/conf/logging.properties are really the same??

Comment: Also, just in case, you can do a md5 over your war files in DEV and PROD?

Comment: @Perimosh - As I said earlier "They both include logging.properties, but the files are identical". I pulled the files to my workstation, used BeyondCompare. They are identical. The same WAR is deployed on DEV and PROD.

Comment: Did you check both catalina.properties from both servers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the OP. Problem solved.

Was due to Jelastic not refreshing webapps folder following Tomcat deploy. Therefore, old log4j2.xml was being used.

Bob